# Laravel 5.3 timestamp change between display and insert in database

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I use Laravel 5.3 for my project.

When I insert data in database, the timestamp **planned_at** is before **2017-25-01 12:50:10**

In database, the timestamp **planned_at** becomes **2019-01-01 12:50:10**.

Have you got an idea? Thanks.

Comment: why you are using **planned_at**

Comment: To schedule a plannification.

Comment: 2017-25-01 12:50:10 isn't valid date ;)

Comment: Your format is wrong, the datetime/timestamp field in the database expect a format of `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` and you gave it `"Y-d-m H:i:s"`, just replace the month and the day positions

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual implementation it's hard to tell what could be the issue. But if I were you I'd plan my implementation as follows.

In you model declare `planned_at` under [dates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) array.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $dates = [
        'planned_at'
    ];
}
```

Then in where you persist date

```
$date = Carbon::parse($yourDateString);
// save $date in you database
```

make sure you

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

at the top of the page.

Read [more](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon) on [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)